# Gtk+ 3.0 change fontcolor of statusbar

Tags: colors, gtk, statusbar

How can I change the fontcolor of the statusbar?

I have no Idea.

I found `gtk_widget_modify_text`but don't know how to use it!

EDIT:

I tried this, but doesnt worked:

```
GdkRGBA font_color;
font_color.red = 1;
font_color.green = 0;
font_color.blue = 0;
font_color.alpha = 1;
gtk_widget_override_color(statusbar, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &font_color);
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you try to read the [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-color)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `gtk_widget_override_color` and use it with `GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL` and the corresponding `GdkRGBA` color you wish to set. See the [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.2/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-override-color) for further details.

Here is an example written in vala:

```
using Gtk;

public class Application : Gtk.Window {
        public Application () {
                this.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);
                this.set_default_size (100, 50);

                Gtk.Statusbar bar = new Gtk.Statusbar ();
                this.add(bar);

                uint context_id = bar.get_context_id ("example");
                bar.push (context_id, "Message ...");

                Gdk.RGBA font_color = Gdk.RGBA ();
                font_color.red=0.5;
                font_color.green=0;
                font_color.blue=0;
                font_color.alpha=1;
                bar.override_color (Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, font_color);
        }

        public static int main (string[] args) {
                Gtk.init (ref args);

                Application app = new Application ();
                app.show_all ();
                Gtk.main ();
                return 0;
        }
}
```

[image: screenshot of example application]

Here is a C example. It is a modified version of the [statusbar example](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/x919.html).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <glib.h>

GtkWidget *status_bar;

static void push_item( GtkWidget *widget,
                       gpointer   data )
{
  static int count = 1;
  gchar *buff;

  buff = g_strdup_printf ("Item %d", count++);
  gtk_statusbar_push (GTK_STATUSBAR (status_bar), GPOINTER_TO_INT (data), buff);
  g_free (buff);
}

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *vbox;
    GtkWidget *button;

    gint context_id;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    /* create a new window */
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_set_size_request (GTK_WIDGET (window), 200, 100);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "GTK Statusbar Example");
    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
                      G_CALLBACK (exit), NULL);

    vbox = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 1);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), vbox);
    gtk_widget_show (vbox);

    status_bar = gtk_statusbar_new ();      
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), status_bar, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (status_bar);

    /* here comes the color change */
    GdkRGBA font_color;
    font_color.red = 1;
    font_color.green = 0;
    font_color.blue = 0;
    font_color.alpha = 1;
    gtk_widget_override_color(status_bar, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL, &font_color);

    context_id = gtk_statusbar_get_context_id(
                          GTK_STATUSBAR (status_bar), "Statusbar example");

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("push item");
    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
                      G_CALLBACK (push_item), GINT_TO_POINTER (context_id));
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (vbox), button, TRUE, TRUE, 2);
    gtk_widget_show (button);              

    /* always display the window as the last step so it all splashes on
     * the screen at once. */
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Work at textboxes but not at the statusbar

Comment: Doesn't the screenshot show what you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't work cause im using GTK version 3, there the statusbar is not longer a container, so it doesn't work!

Comment: I compiled it with `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` and `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` and it worked.

Comment: By the way, the official [reference](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStatusbar.html) even says it inherits from GtkContainer.

Comment: Don't ork at mine system! I did a recording so check out the link: http://i.imgur.com/AFPYqLB.gif

Comment: Have a look at this (video was slowed down by the conversion) https://mediacru.sh/Hwy9jne_D_S6  Maybe it is a bug of elementary OS. However, the code is working.

Comment: Hm ok i will try some fixes, btw, which os do you use? AND! Do you know how i can fix the bug? I have no idea

Comment: Still don't know how to fix my problem, maybe elementaryOS bug, but how to fix it?

Comment: I am using Fedora with Gnome 3.10. You should try to ask the people in the gtk+ and elementary os irc channel. Either they can help you or you need to file a bug.

Comment: gtk_widget_override_color is deprecated but it does work, I've tested it on Fedora 25 Gtk+ 3.22. Since the question is not OS specific, this answer should be considered correct. There is also another method, which would be to add a GtkLabel to the statusbar container and with markup set the font color. Other way, would be to use CSS theming.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to retrieve the "label" widget of the status bar to change its attributes. This code changes font and size of the status bar (GTK 2):

```c
PangoFontDescription *pfd = pango_font_description_from_string("Consolas 8");
GtkWidget *w = gtk_statusbar_get_message_area(GTK_STATUSBAR(statusbar));
GList *gl = gtk_container_get_children(GTK_CONTAINER(w));
GtkWidget *ch = GTK_WIDGET(gl->data);
GtkLabel *label = GTK_LABEL(ch);
printf("Number of children: %d  Text: %s\n", g_list_length(gl), gtk_label_get_text(label)); 
//prints 1 and the current message of the statusbar
gtk_widget_modify_font(ch, pfd);
g_list_free(gl);
pango_font_description_free(pfd);
```